# How to prevent react-router adding # to url?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router

Like the title says how can i prevent adding the # at the end of url.

routes.jsx

```
(export default (withHistory, onUpdate) => {
 const history = withHistory?
              (Modernizr.history ?
                browserHistory
              : hashHistory)
            : null;
return (
<Router history={history} onUpdate={onUpdate}>
  <Route path='/' component={App}>
    <IndexRoute component={quotes} />
    <Route path='/app/search' component={SimpleSearch} />

    <Route path='pathName' component={Blank1} />
      <Route path='pathName/:category' component={Blank1}/>
      <Route path='pathName/:category(/:page)' component={Blank1}/>
    <Route path='app/:id' component={Blank1} />

  </Route>

</Router>

);
};
```

method in blank1.jsx

```
method(current,previous){
    const category= this.props.params.category;
    const page = current;
    const path = `/pathName/${category}/${page}`;
    browserHistory.push(path);
...
}
```

I tried lots of things but couldn't get the link without the #.
It adds # to the end and keeps triggering the componentWillReceiveProps where I change state with this.setState. And also in navigation by none of the nav items aren't active because of the #

Comment: you should use browserHistory to get urls without hash

Answer (score 0):

You are referring to `clean` URLS.

You want to use `browserHistory` instead of `hasHistory`/

You then need to add a `*` route in your server, so that all requests are routed through React Router.

Something like this at the end of your server routes:

```
app.get('*', function (req, res) {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'index.html'))
});
```

For more info checkout [this example](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router-tutorial/tree/master/lessons/10-clean-urls)

Comment: in my server.js i have
app.get('*', function(req, res, next) {
  renderHTML(req, res, next);
});